# mat-tab-nav-bar is not showing arrow to scroll the tabs in horizontal

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I am working on Angular Material V7. I am expecting the same behavior of Mat-tab-group for `mat-tab-nav-bar`. In mobile view `mat-tab-nav-bar` is not showing arrow to scroll the tabs in horizontal.

```html
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
                    [routerLink]="link.path" routerLinkActive 
                    #rla="routerLinkActive"
                    [active]="rla.isActive" matTooltip="{{ link.label }}">
                    {{ link.label }}
    </a>
</nav>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Solved in a very similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62872132/2419584